# Is there a way to make sure that my laptop doesn't exit sleep-mode?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I often have the following problem: I pack up my laptop, but forget to unplug/turn-off my mouse before doing the packing.

Then soon after, I'll move the mouse.. causing my sleeping PC to wake up again. The problem is that the PC is in  my suitcase and turns on and drains the battery.. and also heats up alot. I'm worried I'll eventually burn the fan or other parts.

Is there a way to prevent this via software? I can't figure a way to avoid having this happen.

for the record, a Lenovo T430 is my machine
thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the mouse from waking up the PC through Device Manager:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Run menu
2. Type `devmgmt.msc` and hit enter/click OK to open Device Manager
3. Expand **Mice and other pointing devices** and double-click your mouse in the list
4. Go to the **Power Management** tab and uncheck **Allow this device to wake the computer**
5. Click OK and close Device Manager.

[image]